# ngrx dispatching action on component (associated with a route) init

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-router, ngrx-effects

angular 5+, ngrx 4+

What I'm trying to do is trigger `ARTICLES_LIST_REQUEST` when `ArticlesListComponent`, associated with `path` `/articles` is initialised.

There's a plethora of ways to do it, using `dispatch` inside `ngOnInit`, using `dispatch` on a guard for example, but what I want to do instead is to use `@ngrx/router-store`, listen to `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` and map it to `ARTICLES_LIST_REQUEST` (actually `ARTICLES_LIST_PARAMS_SET`, to save current route params to the store, but it doesn't matter), now there's a couple of problems with that.

Since effects, even those registered with `forFeature`, are running globally, if I were to set up this effect listening to `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` inside multiple module (articles, people, brands etc.), it would run multiple times, triggering all the actions at once, so I'd need a way to filter it only for the route I'm interested in.. but how? Since there are no named routes in angular router and navigation action returns a snapshot of the whole tree, there's no way to know that the particular route just activated. What I'm doing at the moment is checking and filtering by the url, for example whether it begins with `/articles` and whether the next character is not `/` (to filter out `/articles/<id>`. But I'm really disliking it, doesn't really feel like it will safely cover all the cases.

There used to be a way to pause / start / unsubscribe / subscribe effects inside a component, which I don't think is really possible anymore, but it would be moving the responsibility back to component, which wouldn't be much better than dispatching the action from component / guard.

Should I not be using `router-store` for this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with:

1) Add a unique `name` to route definitions's `data`

```js
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/articles',
    component: ArticlesListPage,
    data: {
      name: 'articles-list'
    }
  }
];
```

2) create a custom [serializer](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/api.md#custom-router-state-serializer) for `router-store` that extracts only `params`, `queryParams` and a `name` (from `data.name`) for each child in tree

```js
function createSerializedTree(node: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  const tree = {
    queryParams: node.queryParams,
    params: node.params,
    name: node.data.name,
    children: node.children.map(createSerializedTree),
    firstChild: undefined
  };

  tree.firstChild = tree.children[0];

  return tree;
}
```

3) create a function for `let` that filters and maps to the first route with name matching the one you provide

```js
const _checkIsNodeHasName = (name: string, node: SerializedRouterNode) => {
  if (node.name === name) {
    return node;
  } else if (node.firstChild) {
    return _checkIsNodeHasName(name, node.firstChild);
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

export const filterAndMapRoute = (name: string) => {
  return (navigationAction$: Observable<RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateUrl>>) => {
    return navigationAction$
      .map(action => action.payload.routerState)
      .filter((state) => !!_checkIsNodeHasName(name, state.root))
      .map((state) => _checkIsNodeHasName(name, state.root));
  };
};
```

Now I can do this

```js
@Injectable()
export class ArticlesEffects {
  @Effect()
  private _onRouteChange$ = this._action$
    .ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
    .let(filterAndMapRoute('posts-list'))
    .map(/* ... */) // map to whatever action I need
}
```

It's more or less just a proof of concept, realistically I'd need to check not only the firstChild but all of children.

I first went with simply the last `firstChild` of the tree, but there are cases where that wouldn't work, for example if you wanted to save `id` from these routes

`/articles/:id/graph` / `/articles/:id/table`, the last `firstChild`, wouldn't contain the `id`, thus the need to find the first child that matches the name and map to that (and filter if none was found).

Comment: I like the use of the data attribute, nice. This article might provide more help in extracting primary firstChild and then you could add to it (mergedRoute) to build up the full tree: https://medium.com/simars/ngrx-router-store-reduce-select-route-params-6baff607dd9

Comment: Been a while, nowaday I'm using a variation of this https://github.com/amcdnl/ngrx-router/blob/master/src/operator.ts#L24

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about those operators, very useful!